# EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "Photo" was found when querying using manager

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I am trying to use typeorm on express but unfortunately am facing this error:

> if (!metadata) throw new EntityMetadataNotFoundError(target)
> ^
> EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "Photo" was found.

Here is my datasource

```js
import "reflect-metadata"
import { DataSource } from "typeorm"
import { Photo } from "./photo"


const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    username: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "ecommerseDb",
    entities: [Photo],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false,
})

// to initialize initial connection with the database, register all entities
// and "synchronize" database schema, call "initialize()" method of a newly created database
// once in your application bootstrap

AppDataSource.initialize()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("database connected successfully")
        // here you can start to work with your database
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => console.log(error))
export default AppDataSource
```

I am following the documentation but each time I try to query, I get the mentioned error

```js
const photo = new Photo()
photo.name = "Me and Bears"
photo.description = "I am near polar bears"
photo.filename = "photo-with-bears.jpg"
photo.views = 1
photo.isPublished = true
const query = async () => {
    await AppDataSource.manager.find(Photo)
    console.log("Photo has been saved. Photo id is", photo.id)
}
query()
```

Here is the photo entity

```js
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm"
@Entity()
export class Photo {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number
    @Column({
        length: 100,
    })
    name: string
    @Column("text")
    description: string
    @Column()
    filename: string
    @Column()
    views: number
    @Column()
    isPublished: boolean
}
```

When I call `query` function inside `AppDataSource.initialize()`, it works fine but I need to understand why and why it's not working when query is used outside `AppDataSource.initialize()`

I am using Typescript.

Comment: Can you show your `Photo` class?

Comment: hi @RahulSharma...i have provided the entity

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because your code is not waiting for the `initialize` method to complete. It's happening asynchronously and when you query using the `AppDataSource.manager.find`, datasource isn't initialized yet. In order to fix this you should do:

```
await AppDataSource.initialize();
```

`initialize` method of `DataSource` class returns a `Promise`. See [reference](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/a100a7a7f1c17432549e5e93fb141d0f52062213/src/data-source/DataSource.ts#L226). You can use `try...catch` to catch any error in your datasource file.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the `AppDataSource.initialize()` must be done before `await AppDataSource.manager.find(Photo)` in your code.

You can try by following:

Replace
`AppDataSource.initialize().then(() => {console.log("database connected successfully")}).catch((error: Error) => console.log(error))` by `await AppDataSource.initialize()` and put them before `await AppDataSource.manager.find(Photo)`